# Gradle - Include Properties File

Tags: gradle

How would I include a properties file in Gradle?

For example in Ant, I could do the following:

```
<property file="${basedir}/build.properties" />
```

Comment: Related: http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1419

Comment: I find responses so far disappointing.  I was hoping for a solution that worked like "`include`" or "'`apply`" or even "`import`".  Otherwise there's a good opportunity to _invent_ an ApplyPropertiesFile plug-in I say!!

Comment: There was a JIRA feature request for this facility that got closed last month.  I put my  two-bob's worth here: [Support loading of named ".properties" files as project properties](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1534) -- Comments and improvements are welcome.  Most of all I think the Gradle folk need to VOTES for something to happen.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could do it using the java syntax, e.g.:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
InputStream ins = new FileInputStream("/path/file.properties")
props.load(ins)
ins.close()
```

This should work in any groovy script. There might be a more "groovy" way of doing it though, using closures or some other fancy shortcut.

EDIT: "in" is a reserved word in groovy. A variable can't be named that way, renaming it to "ins"

Comment: Yes, but this is a 'Java' answer when the question is clearly labeled as a 'Gradle' question.  If your question was "how do I load a properties file in Java" then this is the right answer, but there are many such answers on Stack Overflow.  I would say this answer should be edited to show it within the context of a build.gradle file.

Comment: @djangofan Gradle uses Groovy which can use Java syntax.. i.e. you can use this directly in build.gradle

Comment: And if a property contains a dot (e.g. `source.dir`), then you can use this property this way: `println props."source.dir"`

Comment: You could easily use this method, then iterate across the properties and add them to the `Project` via the [`ExtraPropertiesExtension`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html)

Comment: It makes sense to close the property file.
I've seen a couple of copies of this snippet in different projects.

If gradle running in the daemon mode this would cause a memory leak.

Comment: aren't we supposed to close the stream afterwards?

Comment: @HendraAnggrian Yes, modified the snippet to show that.

Comment: This should use a try {} finally {ins.close()} so an exception in load doesn't leave the file open. Or, in the java 7+ era, use a try (...) { ... } using the Closeable feature.

Answer (score 42):

I would actually recommend using Gradle's default properties file.  If you put the properties in `gradle.properties` in the same directory as the `build.gradle`, they will automatically be available.

See the [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).

Comment: This solution maynot be scalable for dynamic properties.

Comment: But be aware that those properties can be overridden by a gradle.properties file in the user's home directory.

Comment: @dnault isn't it the other way? Properties inside build.gradle will override properties in project directory, which override properties in home directory.

Comment: @ataulm It may seem counter-intuitive at first, but properties in the user's home directory *do* override properties in the project directory. Here's the [relevant documentation](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html). In practice, this turns out to be a *good thing*.

Answer (score 35):

What you propably are looking for is something like:

```
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream("$project.rootDir/profile/"+"$environment"+".properties"))
    props.each { prop ->
      project.ext.set(prop.key, prop.value)
    }
```

Your properties should then be accessible directly through their name.
I.e.:

```
  println "$jdbcURL"
  println project.jdbcURL
```

Theres probably a reason (shadowing?) why its a bad idea to do this? Not sure why its not supported out of the box or can be found somewhere else.

Comment: any reason why its not implemented even till now? i need this kind of support badly for my gradle mult-project build..

Answer (score 12):

### For Gradle 1.x (deprecated in Gradle 2.x)

To include your .properties file you can just use something like this:

```
    apply from: "version.properties"
```

and that's it!

Comment: Looks like this is going to be deprecated in gradle 2.0 

`"Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties."`

Comment: @PrakashNadar Just declared the corresponding properties in gradle.build file and the warning disappeared for me. For example ext{versionNumber = 0}. This will create the property and loading the appropriate .property file will init it with the value from the file.

Comment: THIS DOESN'T WORK

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I include a .csv  file in my .jar  that Gradle builds:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src/main/java'
      output.classesDir   = 'build/classes/main'      
    }
    resources {
      srcDir 'src/main/resources'
      include '*.csv'
      output.resourcesDir = 'build/resources/main'
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when my application loads the resource, that is done independently of Gradle.

Comment: Keep in mind that my answer is not a very good representation of how to configure Gradle, but in this case, it does show one method of getting a .csv file to be included.

Comment: Did I miss something here? As far as I can tell, the question is about importing property strings as variables _into the Gradle build script_, while this answer tells how to include a file in one of the built artifacts. Am I wrong?

Comment: @EmilLundberg He did not ask "how do I load properties from a file into my build script".  So, you should be able to understand how someone like me might think he is referring to including a file (from resource dir) that isn't being included in his build.  I took it to imply that he meant, the build was not including a resource in his archive.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. I was just a little confused since the question does include an Ant example that imports properties into the Ant build script.

Answer (score 3):

Use GRADLE_USER_HOME env variable to set gradle's home directory. Put there gradle.properties file and set parameters.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

> The properties file in the user's home directory has precedence over
>   property files in the project directories.

Comment: Watch out: changing `GRADLE_USER_HOME` has side effects (for example, the `cache` directory is under the user's home, storing downloaded dependencies).

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works unless you want to add the properties to the project, since this is the first search result I'll add my solution which works in gradle 3.x.  An easy way to do it is through ant.

```
ant {
    property(file: 'properties.file')
}
```

If you need to convert the property to Camel Case for easy access in your script (remember dot based syntax expects and actual object to exist in gradle):

```
println "property value:{dot.property.from.file}" //this will fail.
def camelCaseProperty = project.getProperties().get("dot.property.from.file")
println "camelCaseProperty:${camelCaseProperty}"  //this wont fail
```

If you need a default value if it's not specified:

```
def propertyWithDefault = project.getProperties().get("dot.property.from.file","defaultValue");
```

By using this method, at least with IntelliJ/Android Studio, the IDE will link your properties file and gradle script and add completion, reference checking, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
import java.util.*
// ...

val properties = Properties().apply {
    load(rootProject.file("local.properties").reader())
}
val prop = properties["propName"]
```

In Android projects (when applying the android plugin) you can also do this:

```kotlin
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.gradleLocalProperties
// ...

val properties = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir)
val prop = properties["propName"]
```

Comment: you are real hero

Answer (score 2):

I have been sorely missing this feature of Ant, especially the in-property replacement like `work.dir=${basedir}/work`.  With some of the large builds I work with that perform lots of environment setup for automated tests, there are some tasks that just need user and environment configurable settings.  The simple "gradle.properties" just isn't enough, especially for settings that are shared across multiple projects.

I put together an example gradle file that manages a reasonable property loading scheme: [load-properties.gradle](https://gist.github.com/groboclown/a5cf5622641b2251d18adbe5561015f1).  This lets the project define exactly the properties it uses in a `default-properties.gradle` file, and allows users to define their local settings to override them.  Because the "property" files read in are gradle scripts, you can include extra logic in them, and the values aren't limited to just strings.

Additionally, it allows for defining a per-environment properties file to use (such as "mac", or "jenkins-machine", or "remote") by passing in a "-Penv=(env name)" parameter to gradle.

Answer (score 0):

In your task (jar or any other task) you can do this way to include any file into the destination folder

```
jar{

    //jar task related code

   from("src/main/......(source)") { 
     include 'xxx.properties' into('com/.....(destination)') 

   }

}
```