# How do I read properties defined in local.properties in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, properties-file

I have set `sdk.dir` and `ndk.dir` in *local.properties*.

How do I read the values of `sdk.dir` and `ndk.dir` in the *build.gradle* file?

Comment: the real question is: why isn't this built in to the android gradle plugin?!?!?!?!

Comment: @Armand: maybe because `local.properties` is in use for Android Studio's own local config, and having another file of the same name might create a little bit of confusion. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306091/1587329 below

Comment: @Armand it's a pity this was not built in 5 years ago, but later this was added: `android.getSdkDirectory()` simply works.

Comment: Related post: [Sign APK without putting keystore info in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20562189/8583692)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle - Include Properties File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749384/gradle-include-properties-file)

Answer (score 178):

You can do that in this way:

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
def ndkDir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
```

Use `project.rootProject` if you are reading the properties file in a sub-project `build.gradle`:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle <-- You are reading the local.properties in this gradle build file
│   └── src
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── local.properties
```

In case the properties file is in the same sub-project directory you can use just `project`.

Comment: What it is "project.rootProject"?

Comment: Added a brief explanation

Comment: What do you mean with project? My ide is giving me an error. How do I get project path.

Comment: Inside a `build.gradle` file `project` is a variabile which refers to the current project. If you have strange errors ask a new question.

Comment: If I copy your code inside a utility class in app/src/main/java/my_package_name/Utils.java it cannot be resolved. How can I read local.properties from a Utility class?

Comment: As I said it would be better if you ask your own question. BTW you should read the local.properties file in the `build.gradle` and generate one or more `BuildConfig` fields. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java/17201265#17201265

Comment: I want to write a library that reads custom values declared in a property file by the user of the library. These values are different depending on who is using the library. It's the first time I'm facing this situation and I'm trying to figure out how to do that...

Comment: What if I don't know the latest version of sdkdir build-tools, and I want gradle to handle it for me?  For example, finding **sdk.ri/build-tools/24.0.0/**

Answer (score 56):

local.properties

```
default.account.iccid=123
```

build.gradle -

```
def Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").newDataInputStream())

defaultConfig {

    resValue "string", "default_account_iccid", properties.getProperty("default.account.iccid", "")
}
```

and in code you get it as other string from Resources -

```
resources.getString(R.string.default_account_iccid);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. How is it not selected? The chosen answer doesn't even provide a solution??

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties' in my case

Comment: OK, could I put `Properties` declaration in `defaultConfig`? Why do people put it outside of `defaultConfig` scope?

Comment: If I try to access this variable in manifest file, it won't build (says resource not found)

Comment: Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.HashMap.load() is applicable for argument types: (DataInputStream) values: [java.io.DataInputStream@3e893459]
Possible solutions: clear(), clear(), clone(), sort(), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure)

Answer (score 21):

now it's more simple with [the new google plugin](https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin)

1- add your property

```
sdk_dir="sdk dir"
```

2- add the plugin (Groovy)
this in top-level (project level)

```
buildscript {
 dependencies {
     classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:1.3.0"
 }
}
```

and in your app Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}
```

3- build your project
4- access it like this

```
BuildConfig.sdk_dir
```

Comment: This works and easy without need context for getString()

Comment: Thanks a lot ! after a lot of hussle this worked

Comment: I am not able to access sdk_dir using BuildConfig

Comment: This is not working at all

Comment: This do work till now. I have just implement a map sample and find that it seems to be a part of google map support from google. Thanks a lot Sattar.

The classpath line would look like **id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false** on newer android studio

Comment: It wasn't working for me until I "Rebuild Project"

Answer (score 11):

## Adding the property

The following [Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#properties-files) technique shows you how to store a property in your local.properties file so that it can be securely referenced by your app.

1. Open the `local.properties` in your [project level](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects#ProjectView) directory, and then add your property like the following example:

```
sdk.dir=MY_SDK_DIR
```

2. In your app-level `build.gradle` file, add this code in the `defaultConfig` element. This allows Android Studio to read the `sdk.dir` property from the `local.properties` file at build time and then inject the build variable into your `res/gradleResVlues.xml`.

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
if (rootProject.file("local.properties").exists()) {
    properties.load(rootProject.file("local.properties").newDataInputStream())
}

resValue "string", "sdk_dir", properties.getProperty("sdk.dir", "")
```

3. Save the files and sync your project with Gradle.
4. Retrive your string using the following code

```
getString(R.string.sdk_dir);
```

Comment: How does this work with versioning systems? You would not want to create commits and pull requests everytime that you wanted to change a property

Comment: In the same way you use the other method

Comment: What other method? Would this resolve the values during build without touching the source code?

Comment: The real question is: is local.properties is included in your repository? If so, does it really have to be? If still yes, you will need to version any changes to your properties file.

Comment: No. It is not, as it should be. I saw a method (which I can't find) that loads properties from an external properties file and adds them to ```buildConfigField```, which end up in ```BuildConfig.java``` as static final fields. I thought that was quicker than dealing with XML reading etc.

Answer (score 10):

Although @rciovati's answer is certainly correct, there is also an alternative way of reading the values for `sdk.dir` and `ndk.dir`.

As pointed out in [this blog entry by Gaku Ueda](http://blog.gaku.net/ndk/) (Getting ndk directory) the `BasePlugin` class offers methods for `getNdkFolder()` and `getSdkFolder()`:

```
def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').getNdkFolder()
def sdkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').getSdkFolder()
```

*Note: You may have to change `com.android.application`to `com.android.library`if you are building a library*

This is maybe a more elegant way of reading the folder values. Although it has to be said that the answer provided by @rciovati is more flexible, as one could read any value in the properties file.

Comment: For Gradle 1.1.0 you nee to use `plugins.getPlugin('com.android.library').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()` as can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615439/android-gradle-plugin-1-1-0-getndkfolder-not-found-anymore-any-replacement

Comment: Broken again with the shift to "experimental" plugin :(

Answer (score 10):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts):

```kotlin
import java.util.*
// ...

val properties = Properties().apply {
    load(rootProject.file("local.properties").reader())
}
val myProp = properties["propName"]
```

In Android projects (where you have applied the `android` plugin) you can also do this:

```kotlin
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.gradleLocalProperties
// ...

val properties = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir)
val myProp = properties["propName"]
```

Answer (score 9):

The answer that loads local.properties manually above obviously works, and the next one that requires you to know which plugin was applied should work as well.

These approaches might be a little better for some since they are more generic because they work regardless of whether you're using the Application, Test, or Library plugin. These snippets also give you full programmatic access to all of the Android plugin config (Product Flavors, Build Tools version, and much more):

If you need access in a build.gradle file that is using the Android Gradle Plugin simply access the Android DSL directly as it's now available directly:

```
project.android.sdkDirectory
```

The longer form (below) of this is handy if you're creating custom Gradle Tasks classes or Plugins or simply want to view which properties are available.

```
// def is preferred to prevent having to add a build dependency.
def androidPluginExtension = project.getExtensions().getByName("android");

// List available properties.
androidPluginExtension.properties.each { Object key, Object value ->
    logger.info("Extension prop: ${key} ${value}")
}
String sdkDir = androidPluginExtension.getProperties().get("sdkDirectory");
System.out.println("Using sdk dir: ${sdkDir}");
```

At the time of this posting there is also a handy `adbExe` property that is definitely worth noting.

This code has to execute AFTER the Android Gradle Plugin is configured per the Gradle livecycle. Typically this means you put it in the `execute` method of a `Task` or place it AFTER the `android` DSL declaration in an Android app/libraries' `build.gradle` file).

These snippets also come with the caveat that as you upgrade Android Gradle Plugin versions these properties can change as the plugin is developed so simply test when moving between versions of the Gradle and Android Gradle plugin as well as Android Studio (sometimes a new version of Android Studio requires a new version of the Android Gradle Plugin).

Answer (score 4):

I think it's more elegant way.

```
println "${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}"
```

it works on android gradle 1.5.0 .

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin dsl :

build.gradle file

```
val properties = Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").reader())
...
android{
   buildTypes {


    debug {
        buildConfigField("String", "SOMETHING", properties.getProperty("something"))
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### build.gradle (:app)

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/resources"]
        }
    }
}
```

### app/src/main/resources/yourfile.properties

```
test_feature=test-of-feature
```

### YourClass.kt

```
fun getProperty(key: String): String? {
    val properties = Properties()
    val propertiesFile = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("yourfile.properties")
    properties.load(propertiesFile)
    return properties.getProperty(key)
}

getProperty("test_feature")
```

GL