# Android Gradle Plugin 1.1.0 - getNdkFolder() not found anymore, any replacement?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I just updated android Gradle plugin to 1.1.0 from 1.0.0, and I got this error:

> No signature of method:
>   com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin.getNdkFolder() is applicable
>   for argument types: () values: []

I tried to find diff of gradle plugin 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 but couldn't find anywhere online.

Seems like `getNdkFolder` method has been either changed or removed.

Is there a replacement ? Or any other way to get NdkFolder ?

I'm using that method like this,

> def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin ( 'com.android.library'
>   ).getNdkFolder ()

I have also filed an issue against tools team in Android issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152810

Thank you !

Comment: you want to specify folder where the NDK is or folder where your projects jni code is? ndk.dir can go in 'local.properties' file along with 'sdk.dir'

Comment: As a replacement to getNdkFolder() for build tools 2.3.0 and onwards, see this post [No sdkHandler field in LibraryPlugin after updating to build tools 2.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644226/no-sdkhandler-field-in-libraryplugin-after-updating-to-build-tools-2-3-0/42923520#42923520)

Answer (score 20):

You can get it like this:

```
plugins.getPlugin('com.android.library').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
```

Comment: Thanks, prevented me from looking into Android Gradle Plugin sources

Comment: This seems to no longer work in Android Studio 2.3. See @Cameron's for a solution.

Comment: Yes, starting with 2.3, [Cameron's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31683613/2710246) worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

### The correct way - android.ndkDirectory

The change from `android.plugin.ndkFolder` to `android.ndkDirectory` was documented in the technical doc [Migrating Gradle Projects to version 1.0.0](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0). In addition you should update your android plugin to 2.3.0.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}
```

The `sdkFolder` is internal and will likely stop working just like `ndkFolder` stopped working.

#### Regarding experimental branches

***Search around, the plugin is mature enough you'll have trouble finding reasons to use experimental branches with the NDK.***

There is some discussion about an Experimental version of the plugin breaking `ndkDirectory` which is the documented way to access this value after 1.1. If that changes in a released version I'll update my answer, in the mean time if running experimental plugins is your thing you can hack your way around this bug/feature using @Alex Cohn's answer.

Comment: Broken again with the shift to "experimental" plugin :(

Comment: According to the documentation this should still be correct so I would file a bug if I were you. A quick check yielded no open bug.

Comment: What makes you believe that `android.ndkDirectory` was not part of the big change of the DSL for the next version of Android plugin? Anyways, I found an alternative approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32658072/192373

Comment: The experimental plugin comes with a big red warning label that says anything could change. Until something is actually shipped/documented I don't think we should confuse the answer by adding in notes about experimental versions. In all likelihood it is a bug.

Comment: The truth is, all the credits should go to [Riccardo Ciovati](http://stackoverflow.com/users/321354/riccardo-ciovati): *[How do i read properties defined in local.properties in build.gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22012018/192373)*

Comment: @AlexCohn That is another way to do things, but not necessarily the best. Anytime you introduce strings as arguments to functions the world is little worse off.

Answer (score 4):

I am using gradle 2.2.3 version. The think that worked for me:

def ndkDir = project.android.ndkDirectory

Ref. Link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152810

Answer (score 3):

If in the build.gradle file you can probably use this now that the bug referenced has been marked fixed.

```
project.android.ndkDirectory
```

If you're in a custom Task or Plugin you'll want to use this

```
    def androidPluginExtension = project.getExtensions().getByName("android");
    // Use this for easily viewing the properties available in the extension.
    androidPluginExtension.properties.each { Object key, Object value ->
        logger.info("Extensionprop: ${key} ${value}")
    }
    String ndkDir = androidPluginExtension.getProperties().get("ndkDirectory");
    System.out.println("Using ndk dir: ${ndkDir}");
```

But remember that the Android Plugin would have had to have been initialized, so this will always work in a Task's execute method, but it may not work if Gradle hasn't parsed the Android DSL yet during the Gradle Configuration phase.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Pardo mentioned, you can get it by 
*

> plugins.getPlugin('com.android.library').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()

*

, In case you receive the following error:

```
Error:(9, 0) Plugin with id com.android.library has not been used.
```

You can use the applied plugin : 'com.android.application', therefore the final code will be :

```
def ndkDir = plugins.getPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.ndkFolder
```