# JNI build gradle fails on finding ndk directory

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I set `ndk.dir` in my `local.properties` file. But, when `grade` builds, this line

```
task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
```

throws an error saying that `android.ndkDirectory` is not set. How can I prevent myself to hard code the absolute path of `ndkDirectory` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This property *[has changed its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615439/android-gradle-plugin-1-1-0-getndkfolder-not-found-anymore-any-replacement)* several times since NDK support was introduced. I am not sure it has stabilized now with the "experimental" plugin.

Therefore I would recommend a version independent approach, invented by [Riccardo Ciovati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321354/riccardo-ciovati) in *[How do i read properties defined in local.properties in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22012018/192373)*:

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def ndkDir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
```