# Import hello-neon (ndk samples) to Android Studio with MAC OS X

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to NDK, gradle, and Android Studio (AS) and meet some problem while importing hello-neon (ndk samples) to AS. My operating system is MAC OS X Yosemite.

After seting `ndk.dir` and `sdk.dir` in `local.properties` and write `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` to `gradle.properties`, I still cannot make this program because I cannot find the `cpu-features.h` in `helloneon.c`.

I have searched for several methods. The only valid method is to add

```
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
}
```

to `build.gradle`.

After that, we can Make Project and install it on Android VM. However, the app will crash when I open it. To find the reason, I found that `public native String stringFromJNI()` at `HelloNeon.java` cannot be linked to its implementation at `helloneon.c`. ("cannot resolve corresponding Jni functions")

Still following the instruction provided at stackoverflow, I use ndk-build to build the source code (need to add environment variable pointing to cpufeatures) and add .so files to this project, like
[screen shot of the structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuaQX.png)

**After doing so (adding .so files), it is still said "cannot resolve corresponding Jni functions" at stringFromJNI in `HelloNeon.java`. But it can be "Make Project" and can be successfully run on my VM!**

**I don't know whether it is a good solution because AS still report errors at `HelloNeon.java` even it can be compile.**

Then I try add following sentences to `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jinLibs' 
}
```

It does not change any thing. (these code can be delete. --by bullsy)

I also try to copy `cpu-features.h` and `cpu-features.c` to /main/jni , then we can find the `cpu-features.h` but miss other files.

As a result, I come here to find some help. Can you help point out the mistakes we have made and the correct way to solve it? Although this is a naive problem for  experts to this area, I really appreciate your help as a new man to this area.

Thank you very much!

---

This is my `build.gradle` (Module: app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.neon"
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 4

        ndk {
            moduleName "helloneon"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jinLibs' // <-- Set your folder here!
    }

}
```

This is my another `build.gradle` (Project: hello-neon) :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is my `settings.gradle` :

```
include ':app'
include ':cpufeatures'
```

My Android Studio version is 1.5.1

My ndk version (`./ndk-build -version`) is GNU Make 3.81

Thanks again.

---

**UPDATE**

Thank you bullsy. I added following code in my `build.gradle` :

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('/Users/zhu/AndroidStudioProjects/hello-neon/app/src/main')
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

And got some error information when "Make Project" in `ndk-build`:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:ndkBuild
make: *** /Users/zhu/AndroidStudioProjects/hello-neon/app/main: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Then I use `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio` to start the AS so that AS can read environment variable from bash, these code works!

However, this .so files will be store in "/Users/zhu/AndroidStudioProjects/hello-neon/app/src/main/libs" and these .so file cannot be loaded directly (It seems that the project will only load the .so file in jniLibs/).

As a result, should I add

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' 
}
```

If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code:

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jinLibs' // <-- Set your folder here!
}
```

Because you're using Android.mk, setting `jniLibs.srcDir` to empty is correct. This tells the build system not to override your Android.mk file. In order to build properly, you'll need to call `ndk-build` from your build.gradle and point it to your jni directory. Setting up the call to `ndk-build` might look like this:

```
// call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
    } else {
        commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

These examples are pulled from ph0b's excellent [tutorial](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/) on working with the older version of the NDK. If you are interested in trying the experimental NDK support at some point in the future when you're a little more comfortable, ph0b has posted some great stuff on that [too](http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/).

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake before : although it is said cannot resolve stringFromJNI in `HelloNeon.java`, it can be make and it can work on VM, as long as I copy the .so files (compiled using command line) to jniLibs. What's more, even I delete `jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jinLibs'`, it can still work.  I think your suggestion is to `ndk-build` using AS rather do it by hand. I add these code (revised of course) to my `build.gradle` and it can be run during my make. However, there are some error said `A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build''`, do you know why it happens?

Comment: To be more clear, if I use Terminal provided by AS, the command "ndk-build -C app/src/main/" can work well. Else, error happens when running command 'ndk-build' during "Make Project". One hint maybe that I need to add environment variable when running this command in terminal. But I don't know how to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: There should be some additional error text explaining what the actual error starting ndk-build was. Most likely, ndk-build is not on the path and can't be found. One way to fix this is to use the full path to the ndk-build executable. You can get the full path to the ndk directory from Gradle, but the syntax has changed quite a few times. I think 'project.android.ndkDirectory' should work, but if not, this thread lists the many different syntaxes to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615439/android-gradle-plugin-1-1-0-getndkfolder-not-found-anymore-any-replacement

Comment: I find the reason: ndk-build did not work because of the miss of environment variable. When I fix it by using bash to start AS, it works well. However, another problem happens: ndk-build does generate .so file but in src/main/libs, and this project cannot read .so file from src/main/libs directly. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: You can set the output directory for ndk-build using NDK_LIBS_OUT=<desired directory path>. Just pass it as an argument to ndk-build.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!