# No sdkHandler field in LibraryPlugin after updating to build tools 2.3.0

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I was using the this method to get the NDK directory:

```
project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.library').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
```

Ater updating `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to `2.3` the field `sdkHandler` seems to have been renamed on removed

> Error:No such property: sdkHandler for class: com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin

Is there an alternative way to get the NDK directory path in a library module?

Answer (score 12):

This method will now return the NDK's full path:

```
project.android.ndkDirectory.absolutePath
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was to simply set the `ANDROID_NDK` environment variable. 
More [here](http://www.devsbedevin.com/the-pains-of-building-android-react-native-from-source/).

Answer (score 0):

I've done some digging. Seems that the field is still there but marked as private.

One solution would be to use reflection.

The field is in `com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin` from which `com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin` inherits.

```
LibraryPlugin plugin = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.library')
Class<?> clazz = plugin.getClass().getSuperclass();
Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField('sdkHandler')
field.setAccessible(true)
SdkHandler sdkHandler = field.get(plugin)
System.out.println("Ndk location: " + sdkHandler.getNdkFolder())
```

To be honest i don't really like this solution. I hope to find a better one.

Answer (score -2):

Just downgrade your gradle version to 2.2.3. it will solve the problem