# How do I read properties defined in local.properties in gradle.properties

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my Android Studio project I have proxy settings defined in gradle.properties file, that is synched with Git repo. As long as I have my proxy password defined there, I need to move it into local.properties file. I want to achive smth like this:

in **gradle.properties**:

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=<local.properties>.proxy_pass
```

and in **local.properties**:

```
proxy_pass="PASSWORD"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999829/how-do-i-read-properties-defined-in-local-properties-in-build-gradle

Comment: It's different case

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. However, since you've made your property a `systemProp` you can override its value from the commandline or with an environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't happen, because Java Properties are simple strings, there is no logic applied automatically.

However, you can simply use a `gradle.properties` file in the `.gradle` folder of your user home directory to define environment-related settings instead of project-related settings. This file won't be uploaded to a VCS.