# gradle ignore FileNotFoundException for properties file loading

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

By referencing [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43279079/361100) about `.properties` loading in `build.gradle`, I'd like to know how to ignore when the file is not existed.

Currently, below `build.gradle` file throws FileNotFound exception and cannot proceed compile.

```
def Properties properties = new Properties()
try{
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file("developer.properties").newDataInputStream())
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'PrintLog', properties.getOrDefault("print.log", "false")
    }
}
```

What I want is to make compile whether `developer.properties` is existed or not. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple try-catch block to achieve it as follows:

```
android {
    ....
    def developerPropertiesFile = file(getRootDir().getPath() + '\\developer.properties')
    def developerProperties = new Properties()
    try {
        developerProperties.load(new FileInputStream(developerPropertiesFile))
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        developerPropertiesFile = null;
    }
    ...
}
```

Before usage you can check:

```
if (developerPropertiesFile != null) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Great! Enjoy coding :-)