# Unable to access the API key using BuildConfig

Tags: android, gradle, google-api, api-key, secret-key

I'm using [secrets-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin) to read the API keys that I put in my local.properties.

I've added this code into the root `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"
  }
}
```

For app `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
  id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}

android {
  compileSdk 31
...
}
```

And this is my `local.properties`

```
## This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#
sdk.dir=/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk
apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Then when I tried to access it from any class/application `BuildConfig.apiKey` is not there. Am I missing any steps here? Been trying for few hours but doesn't found any way to make this work.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999829/how-do-i-read-properties-defined-in-local-properties-in-build-gradle

Comment: @HashT Found the way to get properties value from your link. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I end up reading the API value in `local.properties` in app's `build.gradle` and assigning it to `BuildConfig`. This is done under `defaultConfig` tag.

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream()) 
buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"${properties.getProperty('API_KEY')}\""
```

Comment: It's better to define a variable for the input stream and close it after using to avoid memory leak. Or you can use the try-with-resources to close the stream automatically.
e.g. `try (def inputStream = new FileInputStream('local.properties')) { properties.load(inputStream) }`

In addition, if you define the variable in the gradle.properties file, you can get it directly 
 in defaultConfig without using Properties.

Answer (score 1):

1. try and add this line in `app/build.gradle` within the `defaultConfig`

   buildConfigField("String", "apiKey", API_KEY)
2. then try to fetch it

   String apiKey = BuildConfig.apiKey;

Comment: I'm able to get the value by using this code
```buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\" API_KEY\""```
But using this means I need to put the key in app ```build.gradle``` which will be push into git. Which the main reason I'm using this secrets gradle plugin. Am I able using this way but getting the data from ```local.properties```?

Comment: Okay, found it. I use this to load the data from ```local.properties```. ```Properties properties = new Properties()``` ```properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())``` ```buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", ${properties.getProperty('API_KEY')}```

Comment: yes it is generally not a good practice to put apikeys in properties file. But if its just a test project then i guess its fine.

Comment: I see here, everyone recommends to not put keys in local.properties
However, please be considerate enough to let people know where to put it, rather than discouraging a potential workaround. Share the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer didn't exactly work on my 2023 project (Kotlin).

in `local.properties`

```
API_KEY=absdefghijklmnop
```

In my app level `build.gradle.kts` I had to do the following

```
buildFeatures.buildConfig = true // to enable custom build config keys

defaultConfig {
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Build > Clean Project**

**Build > rebuild Project**

Finally:

```
val apiKey = BuildConfig.API_KEY
Text(text = "API KEY ${apiKey}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Build > Clean Project

Build > rebuild Project

works for me