# Android Native - Where to put secret, endpoints, keys?

Tags: android, api, gradle, native, secret-key

AFAIK there are 2 possibilities:

### 1. [local.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999829/how-do-i-read-properties-defined-in-local-properties-in-build-gradle)

```
.
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── local.properties
```

with

```kotlin
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
def ndkDir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
```

### 2. src > build.gradle > defaultConfig || other configs

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"${System.env.API_KEY}\""
}
```

```kotlin
println(BuildConfig.API_KEY)
```

What method should I use?

Comment: Actual secrets should never go into an app since you can unzip or decompile an apk and read all of them. A phone is not a trusted environment like a server

Answer (score 0):

This is the Good Answer for your Question- [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2ckvIzs0nU)

Comment: This is not a good answer though. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231