# How to read an external properties file in Gradle

Tags: gradle

Does Gradle has some built-in tool that allow me to write the following:

```
def loadProperties(String sourceFileName) {
    def config = new Properties()
    def propFile = new File(sourceFileName)
    if (propFile.canRead()) {
        config.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))
        for (Map.Entry property in config) {
            ext[property.key] = property.value;
        }
    }
}

loadProperties 'src/main/resources/jdbc.properties'
```

I mean without declaring new function. Or any other suggestions how to make it more elegant?

Comment: There's no built-in mechanism for loading properties. You did it well.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-an-external-properties-file/4263) will be helpful also.

Comment: See the answer to this very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749384/gradle-include-properties-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle - Include Properties File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749384/gradle-include-properties-file)