# Gradle: Read properties from external file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have created a file `version.properties` in my Android project that contains this data:

```
version.code=1
version.name="1.0.0"
```

And now I want to use this properties in `build.gradle` file this way:

```
android {

    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode project.property('version.code')
        versionName project.property('version.name')
    }
    ...
}
```

But, obviously, it doesn't find the properties. How can I add this file to classpath so that I can use its properties?

Comment: Probably this answer is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749384/gradle-include-properties-file/33484783#33484783.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle - Include Properties File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749384/gradle-include-properties-file)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To read values from a **generic properties file** you can use something like this:

```
def Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = file('../version.properties')   //pay attention to the path
def versionCode;
if (propFile.canRead()){
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    if (props!=null && props.containsKey('version.code') && props.containsKey('version.name')) {

        versionCode = props['version.code']
        ....

   }
}
```

**Using the standard** `gradle.properties` you can do:

```
VERSION_NAME=1.2.1
```

Then in your `build.gradle` you can use:

```
versionName project.VERSION_NAME
```

**Another way** is to set these values in a `.gradle` file (for example in your top-level file)

```
ext {
  myVersionCode =  ...
  myVersionName =  ...
}
```

Then in your `module/build.gradle` file you can do:

```
versioneCode   rootProject.ext.myVersionCode
```

Comment: image getting this error --->Error:(24, 0) No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [1]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), split(java.lang.String), take(int), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
<a href="openFile:/home/arpitjoshi/Pictures/MetaDataExtraction/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>