# Gradle - Load properties from a .properties file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am getting this error while trying to add `db.properties` file in `build.gradle` file

build.gradle:

```
allprojects {

    apply from: 'db.properties'
    apply from: 'deployment.properties'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

}
```

db.properties:

```
db=blal
dbUsername=/bilal/home
```

Error I am getting is:

```
* Where:
Script 'camelawsextractionservicesb/db.properties' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find property 'blal' on root project 'CamelExtractionServices'.
```

Comment: You cannot `apply from` a properties file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle - Include Properties File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749384/gradle-include-properties-file)

Comment: There was a JIRA feature request for this facility that got closed last month.  I put my  two-bob's worth here: [Support loading of named ".properties" files as project properties](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1534) -- Comments and improvements are welcome.  Most of all I think the Gradle folk need to VOTES for something to happen.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to load properties from an `.properties` file, I would try something like this:

```
ext.additionalProperties = new Properties().load(file("db.properties").newReader())
ext.someOtherProperties = new Properties().load(file("foo.properties").newReader())
```

Then you can access your properties:

```
println additionalProperties['db']
println someOtherProperties['bar']
```

Comment: If I want to add two different properties file in same `build.gradle` file, How will I manage it?

Comment: You'll need two properties objects wont you? Just like in java.

Comment: I'm getting `No signature of method: java.util.Properties.load() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values: [gradle.propteries] Possible solutions: load(java.io.InputStream), load(java.io.Reader), clear(), clone(), find(), sort()`.

Comment: I've edited the answer to add `.newReader()` to fix the compile error.

Comment: You can 'merge' two properties using the `addAll()` method, if you just want a single `Properties` instance.

Comment: How  is that supposed to work if the `load()` method of Properties returns `void` ?

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to utilize `withInputStream` which automatically `close`es a stream:

```java
def props = new Properties()
File propsFile = file("local.properties")
if (propsFile.isFile()) {
    propsFile.withInputStream { props.load(it) }
} else {
    props.put("key", "defaultValue");
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this answer worked when `new Properties.load(file('path').newInputStream())` returned null