# How to read a properties files and use the values in project Gradle script?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am working on a Gradle script where I need to read the `local.properties` file and use the values in the properties file in `build.gradle`. I am doing it in the below manner. I ran the below script and it is now throwing an error, but it is also not doing anything like creating, deleting, and copying the file. I tried to print the value of the variable and it is showing the correct value.

Can someone let me know if this is the correct way to do this? I think the other way is to define everything in the `gradle.properties` and use it in the `build.gradle`. Can someone let me know how could I access the properties in `build.gradle` from `build.properties`?

`build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

// Set the group for publishing
group = 'com.true.test'

/**
 * Initializing GAVC settings
 */
def buildProperties = new Properties()
file("version.properties").withInputStream {
        stream -> buildProperties.load(stream)
}
// If jenkins build, add the jenkins build version to the version. Else add snapshot version to the version.
def env = System.getenv()
if (env["BUILD_NUMBER"]) buildProperties.test+= ".${env["BUILD_NUMBER"]}"
version = buildProperties.test
println "${version}"

// Name is set in the settings.gradle file
group = "com.true.test"
version = buildProperties.test
println "Building ${project.group}:${project.name}:${project.version}"

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.file('build.properties').newDataInputStream())
def folderDir = properties.getProperty('build.dir')
def configDir = properties.getProperty('config.dir')
def baseDir  = properties.getProperty('base.dir')
def logDir  = properties.getProperty('log.dir')
def deployDir  = properties.getProperty('deploy.dir')
def testsDir  = properties.getProperty('tests.dir')
def packageDir  = properties.getProperty('package.dir')
def wrapperDir  = properties.getProperty('wrapper.dir')


sourceCompatibility = 1.7
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
     maven { url "http://arti.oven.c:9000/release" }
  }

task swipe(type: Delete) {
         println "Delete $projectDir/${folderDir}"
         delete "$projectDir/$folderDir"
         delete "$projectDir/$logDir"
         delete "$projectDir/$deployDir"
         delete "$projectDir/$packageDir"
         delete "$projectDir/$testsDir"
         mkdir("$projectDir/${folderDir}")
         mkdir("projectDir/${logDir}")
         mkdir("projectDir/${deployDir}")
         mkdir("projectDir/${packageDir}")
         mkdir("projectDir/${testsDir}")
}
task prepConfigs(type: Copy, overwrite:true, dependsOn: swipe) {
    println "The name of ${projectDir}/${folderDir} and ${projectDir}/${configDir}"
    from('${projectDir}/${folderDir}')
    into('${projectDir}/$configDir}')
    include('*.xml')
}
```

`build.properties` file:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
# General Settings
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
application.name  = Admin
project.name = Hello Cool

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
# ant build directories
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
sandbox.dir = ${projectDir}/../..
reno.root.dir=${sandbox.dir}/Reno
ant.dir = ${projectDir}/ant
build.dir = ${ant.dir}/build
log.dir  = ${ant.dir}/logs
config.dir = ${ant.dir}/configs
deploy.dir  = ${ant.dir}/deploy
static.dir =  ${ant.dir}/static
package.dir = ${ant.dir}/package
tests.dir = ${ant.dir}/tests
tests.logs.dir = ${tests.dir}/logs
external.dir = ${sandbox.dir}/FlexCommon/External
external.lib.dir = ${external.dir}/libs
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle - Include Properties File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749384/gradle-include-properties-file)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

If using the default `gradle.properties` file, you can access the properties directly from within your `build.gradle` file:

`gradle.properties`:

```
applicationName=Admin
projectName=Hello Cool
```

`build.gradle`:

```
task printProps {
    doFirst {
        println applicationName
        println projectName
    }
}
```

If you need to access a custom file, or access properties which include `.` in them (as it appears you need to do), you can do the following in your `build.gradle` file:

```
def props = new Properties()
file("build.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it) }

task printProps {
    doFirst {
        println props.getProperty("application.name")
        println props.getProperty("project.name")
    }
}
```

Take a look at [this section of the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties) for more information.

### Edit

If you'd like to dynamically set up some of these properties (as mentioned in a comment below), you can create a `properties.gradle` file (the name isn't important) and require it in your `build.gradle` script.

`properties.gradle`:

```
ext {
    subPath = "some/sub/directory"
    fullPath = "$projectDir/$subPath"
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
apply from: 'properties.gradle'

// prints the full expanded path
println fullPath
```

Comment: I can access the value of projectDir directly in gradle script.Can you please let me know if I have a value in properties file like this renosandbox.dir = $projectDir/../..        and I tried to access this in my gradle script  def Pathdir = props.getProperty('renosandbox.dir')    println    "${Pathdir}/${folder}" in my task.Do you think it will expand the value of ProjectDir?

Comment: No, it won't expand it automatically. You would need to prepend your property with `projectDir` like so: `def pathDir = "$projectDir/${props.getProperty('renosandbox.dir')}`

Comment: @Sushant Take a look at the edit for another way to do what you're asking.

Comment: Thaks for giving me the right direction and providing me the information of reading the properties file in various ways.

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me solve what was missing in the gradle.properties file so I could run it from the command line.

Answer (score 22):

We can use a separate file (`config.groovy` in my case) to abstract out all the configuration.

In this example, we're using three environments viz.,

1. *dev*
2. *test*
3. *prod*

which has properties *serverName*, *serverPort* and *resources*. **Here we're expecting that the third property *resources* may be same in multiple environments** and so we've abstracted out that logic and overridden in the specific environment wherever necessary:

### **`config.groovy`**

```
resources {
    serverName = 'localhost'
    serverPort = '8090'
}

environments {
    dev {
        serverName = 'http://localhost'   
        serverPort = '8080'
    }

    test {
        serverName = 'http://www.testserver.com'
        serverPort = '5211'
        resources {
            serverName = 'resources.testserver.com'
        }
    }

    prod {
        serverName = 'http://www.productionserver.com'
        serverPort = '80'
        resources {
            serverName = 'resources.productionserver.com'
            serverPort = '80'
        }
    }
}
```

Once the properties file is ready, we can use the following in `build.gradle` to load these settings:

### **`build.gradle`**

```
loadProperties()

def loadProperties() {
    def environment = hasProperty('env') ? env : 'dev'
    println "Current Environment: " + environment

    def configFile = file('config.groovy')
    def config = new ConfigSlurper(environment).parse(configFile.toURL())
    project.ext.config = config
}

task printProperties {
    println "serverName:  $config.serverName"
    println "serverPort:  $config.serverPort"
    println "resources.serverName:  $config.resources.serverName"
    println "resources.serverPort:  $config.resources.serverPort"
}
```

---

Let's run these with different set of inputs:

1. `gradle -q printProperties`

   ```
   Current Environment: dev
   serverName:  http://localhost
   serverPort:  8080
   resources.serverName:  localhost
   resources.serverPort:  8090
   ```
2. `gradle -q -Penv=dev printProperties`

   ```
   Current Environment: dev
   serverName:  http://localhost
   serverPort:  8080
   resources.serverName:  localhost
   resources.serverPort:  8090
   ```
3. `gradle -q -Penv=test printProperties`

   ```
   Current Environment: test
   serverName:  http://www.testserver.com
   serverPort:  5211
   resources.serverName:  resources.testserver.com
   resources.serverPort:  8090
   ```
4. `gradle -q -Penv=prod printProperties`

   ```
   Current Environment: prod
   serverName:  http://www.productionserver.com
   serverPort:  80
   resources.serverName:  resources.productionserver.com
   resources.serverPort:  80
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Another way... in build.gradle:

Add :

```
classpath 'org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.1'
```

And this :

```
def props = new Properties()
file("src/main/resources/application.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it) }
apply plugin: 'flyway'
flyway {
    url = props.getProperty("spring.datasource.url")
    user = props.getProperty("spring.datasource.username")
    password = props.getProperty("spring.datasource.password")
    schemas = ['db_example']
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
import java.util.*
// ...

val properties = Properties().apply {
    load(rootProject.file("my-local.properties").reader())
}
val prop = properties["myPropName"]
```

In Android projects (when applying the android plugin) you can also do this:

```kotlin
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.gradleLocalProperties
// ...

val properties = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir)
val prop = properties["propName"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had this issue come up today.  We found the following worked both locally and in our pipeline:

In build.gradle:

```
try {
  apply from: 'path/name_of_external_props_file.properties'
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

This way when an external props file which shouldn't get committed to Git or whatever (as in our case) you are using is not found in the pipeline, this 'apply from:' won't throw an error in it.  In our use case we have a file with a userid and password that should not get committed to Git.  Aside from the problem of file-reading: we found that the variables we had declared in the external file, maven_user and maven_pass, had in fact to be declared in gradle.properties.  That is they simply needed to be mentioned as in:

```
projectName=Some_project_name
version=1.x.y
maven_user=
maven_pass=
```

We also found that in the external file we had to put single-quotes around these values too or Gradle got confused.  So the external file looked like this:

```
maven_user='abc123'
maven_pass='fghifh7435bvibry9y99ghhrhg9539y5398'
```

instead of this:

```
maven_user=abc123
maven_pass=fghifh7435bvibry9y99ghhrhg9539y5398
```

That's all we had to do and we were fine.  I hope this may help others.

Comment: I did a double-take and started to check the documentation when I saw that you passed a ".properties" file into `apply from`, but I realize now that your "properties" file is really a ".gradle" file.  I recommend you change that file's extension to ".gradle" to properly convey it's format and use to you and your team.