# Gradle property in local.properties

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using Gradle 3.1.2 and I have the following situation.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url repository }
    }
...
```

In the `gradle.properties` file the entry is

```
repository=https://my.url
```

I now want to move this property entry to the `local.properties` file, since it should not be committed into vcs. But `gradle` cannot seem to find it when it is in `local.properties`. 
Where do I need to place the property so `gradle` can find it but its not in vcs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a properties files and use the values in project Gradle script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101589/how-to-read-a-properties-files-and-use-the-values-in-project-gradle-script)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties described you could use a grade.properties file in your GRADLE_USER_HOME directory (default $HOME/.gradle).

Comment: But what if I want to set a system property only for a specific project? Is there no way to do it?