# How to create a file and set in environment variable and get the data inside the file in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, environment-variables, build.gradle

I have some secret keys which I want to store in a File, define the path in the environment variable and then get the values inside it in build.gradle.

I have a file - somekeys and there are 2 3 key-value pair - 
**(Key1 - value 1)
(Key2 - value 2)
(key3 - value 3)**

I will define the path of the file in the system variable. **SOME_KEY** and its path.

I get the file inside the gradle using - **System.getenv("SOME_KEY")**

Now that I have the file How to extract the value from the keys inside the file.

And then pass it to the build(release and debug) type keys like this -

```
resValue "string", "fc_app_id", "getting the key from the file in environment variable".
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding your key to the `gradle.properties` file.

This file can be found in `.gradle` directory in your home directory. You might have to **create** the file if it's not there already.

> Just add the key as key-value pair in gradle.properties file as shown
>   below.

`SECRET_KEY="my-super-secret-key123"`

In your module level build.gradle file add the key as a buildConfigField and if you want to use the key in xml or app code add the key as a resValue.

`buildTypes {
  debug {
    buildConfigField 'String', "SecretKey", SECRET_KEY
    resValue 'string', "secret_key", SECRET_KEY
  }
  release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    buildConfigField 'String', "SecretKey", SECRET_KEY
    resValue 'string', "secret_key", SECRET_KEY
  }
}`

This code can be accessed as shown below:

`String apiKey = BuildConfig.ApiKey;`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [documentation around properties](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/build_environment.html) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101589/how-to-read-a-properties-files-and-use-the-values-in-project-gradle-script) if you really want to load your own file.