# how to write variables to gradle property file when you execute task?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a such case. I need to save curent date after every release build with gradle. Is there any possibility to save date to gradle.properties file that I can read it in the next build job?

My files:
gradle.properties:

```
version=0.0.1
date=
```

build.gradle:

```
task changeDate() {
    file = new File("changelogs/CHANGELOG_RELEASE_FROM_"+getDate()+".md");
    project.setProperty("date",getDate());
}
```

It dosent work and it doesn't save date variable into gradle.properties.

So I wish that I can have a date from release in my gradle.properties file:

gradle.properties:

```
version=0.0.1
date=12.04.2019
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods `getProperty`, `findProperty` and `setProperty` are not directly related to the `gradle.properties` file. Instead, they provide access to properties in the scope of the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instance against which the `build.gradle` gets evaluated. This scope includes a lot of different properties, among them so-called *extra properties* (coming from the `gradle.properties` files).

However, Gradle provides a task type for this functionality called [`WriteProperties`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.WriteProperties.html). Just specify the target file and define some properties:

```
task changeDate(type: WriteProperties) {
    outputFile = file('gradle.properties')
    property 'date', getDate()
}
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve existing properties in the file

Comment: @Mark You may try to [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101589/how-to-read-a-properties-files-and-use-the-values-in-project-gradle-script) the existing properties in a `doFirst` closure and then add them using the method [`properties(...)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/WriteProperties.html#properties-java.util.Map-).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do something like:

```
import java.time.*;

task rel {
    doLast {
        ant.propertyfile(file: "gradle.properties") {
            entry( key: "date", value: LocalDateTime.now())
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose, `rel` is your `release` task or any other task, which execution means, that you release was made. You have to add to it's configuration a `doLast` closure to run some code after task is executed. In this closure you are modifying some property in properties file.

`LocalDateTime` and it's import are added just for example, you can use another method to get current date fo sure.

In your case it could look like:

```
task changeDate() {
    doLast {
        ant.propertyfile(file: "gradle.properties") {
            entry( key: "date", value: LocalDateTime.now())
        }
    }
}
```

But you have to make your `changeDate` executed somehow, if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55657654/7354066) of Lukas I would like to add an example in kotlin (because I struggled with the same issue):

```
tasks.register<WriteProperties>("changeDate") {
    val propertyFile = project.file("gradle.properties")
    outputFile = propertyFile

    doFirst {
        val existingProperties = java.util.Properties()
        propertyFile.bufferedReader().use { existingProperties.load(it) }
        existingProperties.entries.forEach {
            property(it.key as String, it.value)
        }
        property("date", getDate())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to write the following task:

```
tasks.register('writeCompileDatePropertiesFile') {
    def propertiesFile = file('src/main/resources/compileDate.properties')

    doLast {
        
        def compileDate = new Date().format('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')
        def projectVersion = project.version

        propertiesFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
        propertiesFile.createNewFile()
        propertiesFile.withWriter { writer ->
            writer << "compileDate=${compileDate}\n"
            writer << "version=${projectVersion}"
        }
    }
}
```