# Load common properties in build.gradle doesn't work for buildscript

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle.properties

I have multiple projects which share common properties. I want to manage common dependencies in one place so I decided to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37101792/10950272) (from **Edit** section).

```
//properties.gradle
ext {
    pluginVersion = "x.x.x"
}
```

```
//build.gradle
apply from: '/path/to/properties.gradle'

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "some.group:some-plugin:${pluginVersion}"
    }
}
...
```

This results with following error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'pluginVersion'
```

What should I do to load properties from `properties.gradle` file? What am I doing wrong? Is `buildscript` section somehow different than other sections?

I'll just add that before extracting common properties I kept them all in `gradle.properties` file and they worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `buildscript` section runs before `apply ...`

Try moving `apply` inside `buildscript` like that:

```
//build.gradle
buildscript {
    apply from: '/path/to/properties.gradle'
    dependencies {
        classpath "some.group:some-plugin:${pluginVersion}"
    }
}
...
```