# reading property from gradle.properties to configuration.properties

Tags: android

I have two properties file, gradle.proerties and configuration.properties, How can i read value from gradle.properties to configuration.properties,
Is it even possible syntactically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101589/how-to-read-a-properties-files-and-use-the-values-in-project-gradle-script

Comment: this is reading properties file in gradle , my requirement is reading property from property file

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('onfiguration.properties').newDataInputStream())
def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('your_key')
```

Comment: this is reading properties file in gradle , my requirement is reading property from property file –

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_