# Setting Spring boot application properties in gradle custom task

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to run a Spring boot application as gradle task along with some properties required by application to execute. I tried several ways however still unable to make set environment properties required by app to execute.

```
task runJar1(type: JavaExec, dependsOn:bootJar) {
    var jarPath= project(':glacier-glacier').buildDir.path +'/libs/glacier-glacier-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'

    System.setProperty('glacier.dataFilePath', '/path/to/data.dat')
    environment['glacier.dataFilePath'] = '/path/to/data.dat'
    systemProperty('glacier.dataFilePath', '/path/to/data.dat')

    classpath = files(jarPath)
    args '-Drun.arguments=--glacier.dataFilePath='/path/to/data.dat'
}
```

However program startup fails with following error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
> placeholder 'glacier.dataFilePath' in value "${glacier.dataFilePath}"

This application uses Spring boot version 6.0.15

Comment: you need to load properties files like described https://stackoverflow.com/a/37101792/175554 then you can reach them at build.

Comment: Problem is not to access properties, rather passing them to spring boot application from gradle run so that spring boot stop complaining about missing application properties at startup.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix args method argument of the JavaExec task like following:

```
task runJar1(type: JavaExec, dependsOn:bootJar) {
    var jarPath= project(':glacier-glacier').buildDir.path +'/libs/glacier-glacier-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
    classpath = files(jarPath)
    args "--glacier.dataFilePath=/path/to/data.dat"
}
```

Arguments after `--` will be delegated to property and set in Spring Environment. You don't need `-Drun.arguments=` in front.

Or run java command directly

`java -jar glacier-glacier/build/libs/glacier-glacier-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --glacier.dataFilePath=test`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.command-line-args

> By default, SpringApplication converts any command line option arguments (that is, arguments starting with --, such as --server.port=9000) to a property and adds them to the Spring Environment. As mentioned previously, command line properties always take precedence over file-based property sources.

Comment: Logically this answer make total sense. However I still get same error for args    args '--glacier.dataFilePath=asdfs', not sure if gradle internally does some kind of conversion before creating java command.

Comment: this application uses Spring boot version 6.0.15, added this info to question as well.

Comment: Debugged it futher, gradle while startup is dropping args values Logs Starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/java-17.0.10.7.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''. Working directory: /Users/tarun/Documents/codebase/lakehouse-glacier/glacier-glacier Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/java-17.0.10.7.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -jar /Users/tarun/Documents/codebase/lakehouse-glacier/glacier-glacier/build/libs/glacier-glacier-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
args '-Drun.arguments=--glacier.dataFilePath='/path/to/data.dat'
```

with

```
args '-glacier.dataFilePath','/path/to/data.dat'
```

Comment: faced same problem as was suggested @RenatoIvancic answer, problem was somehow gradle is not passing args as part of command line therefore properties are not getting set. Please check my comment there.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all above specified solutions but none of them worked for me. Finally made it work by extending BootRun task instead of JavaExec.

```
task startGlacier(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun, dependsOn: 'build') {
    group = 'Application'

    doFirst {
        systemProperty 'prop1', 'val1'
        systemProperty 'prop2', 'val2'
        var jarPath= project(':glacier-glacier').buildDir.path +'/libs/glacier-glacier-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
        classpath = files(jarPath)
    }
```